# Get all Dates of current weeek starting from monday to sunday mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My select query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CAST(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date AS DATE), "%d"),"-",DATE_FORMAT(CAST(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date AS DATE), "%b"),"-",DATE_FORMAT(CAST(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date AS DATE), "%Y")," ",DATE_FORMAT(CAST(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date AS DATE), "%a")) AS weekList,
    CAST(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date AS DATE) AS listDate 
FROM call_logview 
WHERE YEARWEEK(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
```

which gives me the output below

[image: Result]

I want my select query to be from monday to sunday of current week and, if I add '1' in where condition i.e (YEARWEEK(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date,1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(),1))
it gives me the result starting from previous week sunday,
but I want the result should be from current week monday to sunday.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your SQL request is almost correct, but you should specify the mode as "1" for `YEARWEEK(date, mode)` to be in that way:

`WHERE  YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)`.

So, in your case it should be like that I believe:

`SELECT * FROM call_logview WHERE YEARWEEK(call_logview.CA_N_F_Date, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1);`

Comment: Adding '1' or mode '1' just removed the previous Sunday from the result not able to get coming or current week Sunday.

Comment: @SatishGautam ah, i see, sorry, i read a bit incorrectly. Did you try to use mode '5'?
Is that what you need? 
https://mysqlcode.com/mysql-yearweek/

Comment: If changing the mode will not help then just try to specify the sunday date as separate condition using some various combinations like `WHERE YEARWEEK(@date, 5) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 5) AND YEARWEEK(@date, 5) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 5);`